# Loading texture from MPG

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, gstreamer

### Error:

- `[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture somevideo.mpg`

---

### Actual Result:

- The error is caused and I am not able to use any of the attributes except `play()`

---

### The code for reference:

```
from functools import partial

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App


class VideoPlayScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoPlayScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        box_layout = BoxLayout()
        self.video1 = Video(source="cityCC0.mpg")
        box_layout.add_widget(self.video1)
        self.add_widget(box_layout)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.video1.state)
        self.video1.state = "play"
        print(self.video1.state)
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(print, self.video1.loaded), 0.5)


sm =  ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(VideoPlayScreen(name="video_play"))
sm.current = "video_play"


class OpenCity(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OpenCity().run()
```

The cityCC1.mpg is given by kivy. Check it in the kivy_examples folder.

---

### RunLog:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\kanna\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-03-01_28.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "F:\Python Kivy\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 18 2019, 23:46:00) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "F:\Python Kivy\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.0
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif (img_pil ignored)
[INFO   ] [VideoGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.16.2.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: gstplayer
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7262'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.7262'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture cityCC0.mpg
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
stop
play
False 0.9090554999999999
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
False 0.5063968000000001
False 0.4993861999999998
False 0.49537330000000024
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

It shows the run log as code.

#### As always thanks for reading.

The question after this will get a link to the pastebin with the code log.

Comment: I see that error pretty much whenever I use `Video`, but my apps still work fine. Is your app failing?

Comment: No It works but I am not able to use `loaded` or `eos`. @JohnAnderson

Comment: How are you trying to use `eos` and `loaded`?

Comment: `self.video1.loaded` is always false.

Comment: I haven't done the `eos` I will say you when i finish it.

Comment: the `eos` is working as intended but the `loaded` doesn't work and always false

Comment: Both `eos` and `loaded` work fine for me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Then why does the error shows? @JohnAnderson

Comment: That's a question for the Kivy developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html?highlight=partial#functools.partial), `partial`

> “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments

So that your `print` function in the `partial` is just printing the value of `self.video1.loaded` as it was when the `partial` function was called.

Here is a version of your posted code that prints the current version of `loaded` every half second:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.app import App


class VideoPlayScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VideoPlayScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        box_layout = BoxLayout()
        self.video1 = Video(source="cityCC0.mpg")
        box_layout.add_widget(self.video1)
        self.add_widget(box_layout)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.video1.state)
        self.video1.state = "play"
        print(self.video1.state)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_loaded, 0.5)

    def check_loaded(self, dt):
        print(self.video1.loaded)


sm =  ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(VideoPlayScreen(name="video_play"))
sm.current = "video_play"


class OpenCity(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    OpenCity().run()
```

And the resulting output:

```
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture cityCC0.mpg
stop
play
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event7
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event7>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event4
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event4>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event7". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event4". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
False
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
True
True
True
True
```